# Rails confirmation dialog box button

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, confirm

I am using confirmation dialog box in rails

```
:confirm => "are you sure?"
```

Here the default buttons are **"cancel"** and **"ok"**, instead of this i want "**yes**" and "**no**". Is any other way to do it? Can any one please given quick reply.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [Custom confirmation dialog in Rails](http://rors.org/demos/custom-confirm-in-rails) with customized text.

Comment: it's a dead link :(